# Android autocomplete text view doesn't show suggestions

Tags: android

what is wrong with my code? i am getting the entire list as suggestion in autocomplete text view.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

List<ContactList> contactLists;
List<ContactList> suggestions;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ContactAdapter(Activity context, int id, ArrayList list) {

    super(context, id,list);
    this.contactLists = list;
    suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
}
private View getCustomView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact_layout, null);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    name.setText(contactLists.get(position).getName());
    email.setText(contactLists.get(position).getEmail());

    return  view;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View view , ViewGroup parent)
{
    return getCustomView(position,view,parent);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object result) {

            return ((ContactList) result).getName();
        }


        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null) {

                suggestions.clear();

                for (int contactName = 0; contactName < contactLists.size(); contactName++) {

                    if (contactLists.get(contactName).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                        suggestions.add(contactLists.get(contactName));
                        Log.d(">add>", contactLists.get(contactName).getName() + "");
                    }
                }

                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();

            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count > 0) {

                suggestions.clear();
                suggestions = (List<ContactList>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    };

    return nameFilter;
}
```

}

Tell me how can i get only the filtered results as suggestions.In perform filter method only the filtered results get added. Why it is not getting reflected in publishResults method?

Comment: Remove any text watcher in your textview. Text watchers might cause issues while filtering.

Comment: i have not added any text watcher. i have used autocomplete text view @FebiMathew

Comment: Post your performFiltering method.

Comment: code updated @Febi Mathew

Comment: Remove the below two lines of code from publishResults() ; suggestions.clear();
                suggestions = (List<ContactList>) results.values;

Comment: Also check your logcat for ">add>" values gets printed. Is that okay?

Comment: yes it us getting printed with correct values. On removing that 2 lines also i get the whole list as suggestion. @ Febi Mathew

Comment: ArrayList<ContactList> filteredList = (ArrayList<ContactList>) results.values;
                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    clear();
                    for (ContactList c : filteredList) {

                        add(c);

                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

Comment: when i change my code like this. the suggestions works only for one time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
Log.d(">>","called");
    if(results.count >0){
        suggestions.clear();
        suggestions = (List<ContactList>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
        notifyDataSetInvalidated(); 
}
```

Comment: It also doesnt work. Suggestion list is added properly in performingFilter method but it doesnt get updated for notifyDataSetChanged in publishResults @Ankush Bist